# Change ext4 to NTFS for installing Windows 7

Tags: ntfs, ext4, format

I have a new installation of Ubuntu Mate and I would like to go back to Windows. I'm aware I need to convert it to NTFS and I have tried to make Disks work but it would not allow me to change/shrink my hard drive.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: karel's suggestion should work, *if* you do it from a live DVD/USB system. You cannot (safely and easily) change the size of the filesystem of a running Ubuntu installation. Oh, and always back up your important data before such endeavours!

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall Windows over it, you can delete the old Linux partitions in the Windows installer.

Comment: windows installation could not be completed as hard drive is ext4 and for windows installation it require ntfs format

Comment: When you install Windows, there's a small partition manager, use it.